# How does .net select RuntimeIdentifier in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to find a way to make coworker source code work on Visual Studio 2022. I don't know how to make Visual studio select win10-x64 RuntimeIdentifier as default. Which on command line is **dotnet run -r win10-x64**. I already change TargetOS to Windows and Platform target to x64. But got this error. If I remove all PropertyGroup and keep the one contain win10-x64, then it work.

```
The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'osx.12-arm64' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible.
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);WebApp/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);WebApp/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-musl-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);WebApp/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx.12-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am using window 10 with dotnet version 6.0.7

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, then why are you trying to run macOS and Linux builds?

Comment: @Dai, my coworker use his mac to develop our app and he use command to run source code as default. But I am trying to use VS for debug and another function.